# Django apps , functionalities and models

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is a pretty beginner question, as i have recently learned Django, 
I have these questions since i could not find a clear answer for any.

1. Suppose that we want to build a voting system, and we have users with votes, i have a confusion with the admin user, i should create an app called users? or i should use the users default table by django?
2. for each app i'll have a model, and for sure database-wise, for example a user will have many votes on many projects, therefore how can i connect these relationships across models in the right way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create an app for each model. An app is usually a self-contained, useful entity, that you separate from other apps if you think you'd reuse it in another project in the future. In your case, you could just have one app with various models (Vote, Project).

1. Use the standard Django User model if you're not going to extend it, but if your project becomes bigger and more features arise, you might want to at least create your own User model subclassing AbstractUser because it's difficult to change it later on. Even if you just define

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

you'll be prepared for the day you want to add a field to your user model.

2. No, you don't have a model for each app, you can have multiple models per app. To create relationships, you can use `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField`. If models are tightly related to each other, they belong in the same app. You can have things split in separate apps for the sake of overview, but be careful then with circular references: you can't import Project in the Vote model and Vote in the Project model.

Answer (score 0):

subclass the AbstractUser.

establish relation between various app Models

```
from other_app.models import Model1
    Class Model2(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        relation = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

you can import Model of any app where you need it.